# Android fragments without an activity. Safe to discard?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

So basically I have updated my application from using just activities in a `tabBar` to using `SherlockFragments` in a `supportActionBar`. Not a big deal you would think, and so did I. Everything worked perfectly through all of my tests. However when I released the new version my users started complaining and reporting numerous crashes where fragments throw a NPE when calling `getSherlockActivity()`.

I have read about this problem and it's a problem with restoring instance states and fragments that are no longer attached to any activity but still run for some reason. I haven't found a specific solution for my problem (since I'm using the actionBar to display my tabs instead of a `ViewPager`).

Now my question is if I can simply discard these fragments that return `null` when calling `getSherlockActivity()`? Because they aren't attached to any activity, are they also not visible?

If not, how could I solve this problem? I am already checking the `FragmentManager` for already existing fragments before creating them, but this isn't sufficient.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to discard anything. All necessary checks are needed to be done in a Fragment.
You should try to avoid using getSherlockActivity() before onAttach() is called (since it is called before onCreate(), should be no problems with this, but still) and after onDetach() is called.

```
if (isAdded() && !isDetached())
```

or

```
final SherlockActivity a = getSherlockActivity();
if (a != null)
```

Might work okay.

Comment: This solution would prevent the error reports in my developer console, but I'm afraid it only prevents the symptoms. The activity is needed for example to load resources and such. Also, I think the problem lies with fragments that are detached but somehow remain in memory and are later reused in some way. I'm going to try this approach for now and I'll report back with any findings

Comment: If they are detached, you don't need to do anything with them. They are not visible anymore and remain in memory until destroyed.